# How to get the 1 month before records with age

Tags: c#, linq

My FilterByAgeRequest Class structure

```
public class FilterByAgeRequest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username required")]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? from { get; set; }
    public DateTime? fromTo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to calculate Distinct age with count.

```
var query = await _dataContext.Users
                        .Where(p => p.UserDob != null && p.CreatedAt >= request.from.Date && p.CreatedAt <= request.fromTo.Date) // exclude null DOB's from stats
                        .GroupBy(p => p.UserDob.Year)
                        .Select(g => new FilterByAgeResponseCls{  Age = DateTime.Now.Year - g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                        .OrderBy(g => g.Age).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Above query executes perfectly but now i have new condition. I want to retrieve one month before user age data from today date if the from and fromTo is `NULL`. How to check even from and fromTo in linq.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add condition `(request.from != null && request.fromTo != null)` in `Where` clause as follow:

```
var query = await _dataContext.Users
                            .Where(p => p.UserDob != null && 
                                ((request.from != null && request.fromTo != null) 
                                ? //It means from and fromTo is not null 
                                    (p.CreatedAt >= request.from.Date && p.CreatedAt <= request.fromTo.Date) 
                                : // else means if from or fromTo is null then retrieve data from last one  month
                                    p.CreatedAt > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1) )) 
                            .GroupBy(p => p.UserDob.Year)
                            .Select(g => new FilterByAgeResponseCls{  Age = DateTime.Now.Year - g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                            .OrderBy(g => g.Age).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: any idea why i am getting wrong date count records. in my database `2000-02-02 00:00:00.000` i am having 2000 years two records but above query gives only one data count like for `Age - 20, count-1` :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code, which doesn't require much changes and gives more control over date boundaries:

```
DateTime from;
DateTime to;

if( request.from == null || request.fromTo == null )
{
  from = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);  
  to = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(1);
}
else
{
  from = request.from.Date;
  to = request.fromTo.Date;
}

var query = await _dataContext.Users
              .Where(p => p.UserDob != null && p.CreatedAt >= from && p.CreatedAt <= to) // exclude null DOB's from stats
              .GroupBy(p => p.UserDob.Year)
              .Select(g => new FilterByAgeResponseCls{  Age = DateTime.Now.Year - g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
              .OrderBy(g => g.Age).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: @ketan If answer helped you, you shuold consider accepting it by checking green check mark on the left.

Comment: any idea why i am getting wrong date count records. in my database 2000-02-02 00:00:00.000 i am having 2000 years two records but above query gives only one data count like for Age - 20, count-1 :(

Comment: What are two `CreatedAt` for those two records?

Comment: `CreatedAt  2000-02-02 00:00:00.000 and 2020-02-26 10:46:21.097` and `userDob 2000-02-02 00:00:00.000 and 2000-02-02 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @ketan So none of this will pass `Where` cluase, as it would leave only those records that `CreateAt` is on 2020-02-05 (if you `request.from` or `request.fromTo` is `null`

Comment: i am not getting your point forget about the from and fromTo null i am passing date to them `"from": "12/25/2005",
  "fromTo": "12/25/2020"`

Comment: @ketan Then both will fail `Where` clause

Comment: but i am getting count is 1 for 2000 years record like age-20 count-1